# What is the Aliases pane in Sparrow?

Tags: email, preferences, sparrow

I've just installed Sparrow on my brand new iMac. I found the Aliases pane in Sparrow:

[image]

I've Googled it and found some source say it similars to Shortcut in windows. 
What the Aliases pane for?

Please help guys!

Answer (score 3):

No this is not a file alias (which is the same as a shortcut in windows) but an email alias. An email alias is an additional email address for an existing account.

You create an account with an address email@example.com and then a series of additional address for the very same account (the aliases).

You will have

- one account
- several addresses

It is the same principle as shortcuts and aliases for files but in another context.